# QT and QwebKit can i load javascript file as resource file and use it?

Tags: javascript, qt, embedded-resource, qwebkit

I wonder if I can load Javascript as a resource file to use in QwebKit? 
Well, it doesn't have to be resource file, I am just looking for a method 
to embed JS files into my application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can. I do this in my app. For example:

```
QWebFrame* frame = ui->webView->page()->mainFrame();
frame->evaluateJavaScript(readFile(":/scripts/foo.js"));
```

Where readFile is a function which reads the contents of a file to a string. For example:

```
QString readFile (const QString& filename)
{
    QFile file(filename);
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        return stream.readAll();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Since the filename starts with :, it is read from the resource file. The resource file must have /scripts/foo.js defined, obviously.